# Is a grid graph a vertex-minor of a complete graph?

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory, graph-algorithms, planar-graphs

Consider a graph $G$. A graph $H$ is the vertex-minor of the graph $G$ if $H$ can be obtained from $G$ using vertex deletions and local complementations. For more information, look at Definition 2.1 and 2.2 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.05689.pdf).

Now, let $G$ be a complete graph with $n^{2}$ vertices and let $H$ be a $k \times k$ grid graph, with $k < n$.

For some choice of $k$, is $H$ a vertex-minor of $G$?

Comment: How is it clear from the definition?

Comment: You could simply put the definition of local completion here (even though it is natural, but not common), that's the least you should do to make your question self-contained. Additionally, the answer to this question is trivial by definition, certainly not a research-level question.

Comment: Your question does not appear to be a research-level question in theoretical computer science. For more information about the scope, please see help center, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. Your question might be suitable for Computer Science which has a broader scope, https://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vertex-minors of complete graphs are either complete graphs, star graphs, or edgeless graphs, so this does not hold for $k \ge 2$.

Proof that vertex-minors of complete graphs are complete, star, or edgeless: From a complete graph, vertex deletion gives a complete graph and local complementation gives a star graph. From a star graph, deletion of the central vertex gives an edgeless graph, local complementation of the central vertex gives a complete graph, deletion of an outer vertex gives a star graph, and local complementation of an outer vertex gives again the same star graph. From an edgeless graph, both vertex deletion and local complementation give again an edgeless graph.

Comment: local completion of a complete graph is edge less graph not star.

Comment: @Saeed I think it is a star, using the definition given in the paper "Rank-width and vertex-minors" by Oum '05.

Comment: I'm saying this based on the definition of the linked paper of the OP, it says:  "replacing the induced subgraph on the neighborhood of v, i.e. $G[N_v]$, by its complement". Since the neighborhood of any vertex is the entire graph, its complement is an empty graph. If they mean open neighborhood, they shouldn't use that notation, but I think they mean closed neighborhood anyways (the more natural one that is compatible with their notation). Also if your answer is based on a different definition, then include the other definition here.